# Ktor embeddedServer not starting in Tests

Tags: kotlin, ktor

In my AcceptanceTests, I am trying to start the Ktor embeddedServer by using the following very rude code to be able to check, if the server is started and the tests can start:

```
fun start() {
    val configPath = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("application-acceptanceTest.conf").file
    val appEnvironment = commandLineEnvironment(arrayOf("-config=$configPath"))

    engine = embeddedServer(CIO, appEnvironment)
    engine.addShutdownHook {
        stop()
    }

    engine.start()

    val disposable = engine.environment.monitor.subscribe(ApplicationStarted) {
        started = true
    }

    while (!started) {
        // the start method should not exit until server is started successfully
        Thread.sleep(10)
    }

    disposable.dispose()
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work while running the tests via gradle, but this does work during single test runs in IntelliJ. Any hints are appreciated.

I already tried to add some logging statements, and I do see, that the while-loop is not exiting, and therefor I do believe that the ApplicationStarted-event is not handled correctly.

EDIT: when removing the while-loop the tests are running with gradle, but not in IntelliJ :-(

Answer (score 0):

So, it is all about the correct sequence. It is working with the following code block:

```
fun start() {
    val configPath = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("application-acceptanceTest.conf").file
    val appEnvironment = commandLineEnvironment(arrayOf("-config=$configPath"))

    engine = embeddedServer(CIO, appEnvironment)
    engine.addShutdownHook {
        stop()
    }

    val disposable = engine.environment.monitor.subscribe(ApplicationStarted) {
        started = true
    }

    engine.start()

    while (!started) {
        // the start method should not exit until server is started successfully
        Thread.sleep(10)
    }

    disposable.dispose()
}
```

My lesson-learned here is to first register the event-listener before starting the server :-)